# Set range to end of column in Vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple problem that is kind of annoying me. 
I want to set a variable to a range in excel, where the last row is always different.

```
Set d = Worksheets("sheet1").Range(("A3":Range("A3".End(xlDown))))
```

I have tried different variations of this, but none seem to work. 
The range is on a different worksheet, if that causes any issues.

Is there a simple way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
With Worksheets("sheet1")

Set d = .Range("A3:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

End With
```

Comment: Great thanks! This worked flawlessly. One question why xlup? why does the xldown command not work?